# Angular 7 is it possibe to get a component by its route?

Tags: angular, routes

I'm using `NavigationEnd` event to detect current route after it's been changed like this:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((event) => {
      const navObject = event as NavigationEnd;
      console.log(navObject.url);
    });
```

It works, but it's not very flexible. It gives me the url, e.g. `/user` which is processed by `UserCompoent`. But if I use this url in some logic it will break if I change the route in my router setup. So I will also need to change this name and all other occurences in all of my logic. 
So it would be more preferable if I could find out which component processes the url. I.e.

```
 if (... `instanceof UserComponent`) { ...do somethig user related }
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be add a data in your route config, and use that data to determine which component it is,

example:

`{
    path: '/user ', 
    component: UserComponent, 
    data: { source: 'user' } // <--- unique signature for your component
 }`

and then fetch that data using `ActivatedRoute`,

Another example would be

Checking it via `ActivatedRoute` directly

example:

`constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.component instanceof UserComponent) {
       // do something
     }
}`

reference: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#component

Comment: I like the idea with adding some data to a route. As to second approach, this.activatedRoute.snapshot.component always returns null and the this.activatedRoute.snapshot returns an object like this { path: "", url: ""}

Comment: you're right i check it its always null on my end my bad didn't check and i dont know why, please use the first approach if it caters your need :)

Comment: I've solved it using your advice with data.I think this approach looks elegant enough to be accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

In the app component you will probably have the outlet router, which router outlet has an activate output that returns the active component. From app component you can call a service to notify the current component.

```
<router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
```

And next in the component:

```
onActivate(event) { if (event instanceOf UserComponent) {doAnything()} }
```

Comment: This works, thanks! But I'll need to push some data forward to my components in this case. I'll keep it in mind if I don't find more straight forward solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
).subscribe((event) => {
    let root = this.router.routerState.snapshot.root;
    while (root) {
        if (root.children && root.children.length) {
            root = root.children[0];
        } else  {
            console.log(root.component);
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

will give component name.

Comment: Doesn't look too beautiful, but a fully working solution! Thanks!